# How to validate incoming requests against openapi schema

Tags: go, swagger, openapi, go-chi

I'm trying to validate all incoming HTTP requests against an OpenAPI spec (written in yaml). Ideally something similar to the js package `express-openapi-validator` ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-openapi-validator)). I've been searching for 'openapi validator go' but not having much luck. Is there such a package? Just need something that would save me having to create individual structs in each endpoint definition. I'm using go-chi for routing if that changes anything.

Comment: https://openapi.tools/#data-validators mentions [kin-openapi](https://github.com/getkin/kin-openapi) and a couple of other Go projects.